# How convert a number to a string with the original format in OC ? eg. @1.00 to @"1.00"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to convert a nsnumber to a string but keep the format ,like 1.00 to @"1.00", and the format maybe diffrent somtimes.How to do it in OC ?

Comment: Are you looking for `NSNumberFormatter`? Once in the `NSNumber` I don't think the `NSNumber` would remember how it was "entered", so it shouldn't remember that is had two zeros after the point.

Comment: Yep,this is what i want . I'll recieve numbers from a json and  use the number . Thank you !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.